# Redirect from .aspx url to .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I'm updating my asp.net page from asp.net 2.0 to MVC4.

What I'm trying to do is to basically keep supporting the existing url:

`mypage.com/one.aspx` to be backwards compatible, except that I want to put all aspx pages in a aspx directory, so the new url would be `mypage.com/aspx/one.aspx`.

If I type the url directly `mypage.com/aspx/one.aspx` it works and the page comes up.

Now I'm trying to use RouteConfig to tell it to redirect one.aspx to `aspx/one.aspx`, but I see no way on how to do it. All RouteConfig examples I see use controllers, which is not what I want to do:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "ONE", url: "one.aspx", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Is there a way to use MapRoute in RouteConfig to redirect to another aspx page? I'm using C# with MVC4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must work:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("aspx-redirection", "{page}.aspx", "~/aspx/{page}.aspx");
```

Comment: It didn't work for me ...The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.

Comment: That's not `MapRoute` method. It's `MapPageRoute`. This one does not require anything related to controllers. It just does kind of `Server.Transfer` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is ...
but it's not directly from MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Legacy",
        url: "aspx222/{page}.aspx",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Page", page = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
```

And after in Home in Page

```
public ActionResult Page(string page)
{

    return Redirect(String.Format("/aspx/{0}.aspx",page));

}
```